# How to share an Object Reference using Java Spring's Scheduled Task?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, connection-pooling

I have an object that is used for storing JDBC connections. In simple, this object works as a JDBC connection pool manager. I have several quartz jobs and several schedulers that are configured using Spring's application context. I want to be able to share this object reference with each job. This object is set up with synchronized methods for thread safety. I also have each job to be setup to persist data after execution.

I know that JobDataMap can only be used for primitives and Strings, and it doesn't seem like an option. I want to be able to create this object. Then I want to pass the object reference to each job. Each of the concurrent job will share this same reference. This prevents having unique object references per job.

Where could I start looking into accomplishing this goal? Is it something completely outside the Quartz/Spring realm?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I made a HUGE mistake. I was confusing Spring's Scheduled Task with Quartz. Secondly, I was able to accomplish this using a bean with AutoWired.

Basically, I have the following in each of my "jobs" or tasks:

```
@Autowired
MyCustomDBConnPoolManager mgr;
```

For the actual class code for MyCustomDBConnPoolManager

```
@Service("databaseManager")
public class MyCustomDBConnPoolManager{
```

Instantiating my Context

```
ApplicationContext appContext = 
newFileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

MyCustomDBConnPoolManager manager = appContext.getBean("databaseManager");
manager.initialize();
```

Comment: So the title should become "How to share an Object Reference using Java Spring's Scheduled Task?" and the quartz tag can be removed, right? If so, can you do it - and if you can't, let me know and I'll do it

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I did that. Thanks for bringing that up.